# Bitcoin Transaction Fees When Buying and Selling

Tags: buy-bitcoins, exchange-fees

After dipping my toes in the water with Bitcoin, turning £ into BTC, I immediately noticed around a 10% loss through transaction fees. This seems high firstly. Is this normal?

Secondly, with the rate of raise for BTC at the moment, this 10% loss has repaid itself after around 24 hours (which in itself is crazy and unsustainable), but this value is currently stored purely in BTC. If I want to turn the BTC into £ again, I'm guessing this is going to result in ANOTHER transaction fee of around 10%.

All in all, meaning that the value of BTC would need to raise by at least 20% purely to cover the transaction fees when converting between £ to BTC to £ again.

Have I understood all of this correctly? And here I was thinking that PayPal had some expensive transaction fees!

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin not related to fiat currency, I don't know which wallet you're using but its really of the exchanger.

---

I guess you're using coinbase.com which is not recommend.

Find another wallet to store your bitcoin and exchange your bitcoin locally or using person-to-person trade.

### UPDATE

> To follow on with a few more question, could you please expand. 1)
>   When you say "Bitcoin not related to fiat currency" what do you mean?
>   2) "I guess you're using coinbase.com which is not recommended" - I
>   initially tried with those guys but their website was appaling so
>   couldn't even verify my identity. So no. But out of interest, why are
>   they not recommended? 3) Re. "find another wallet", would you
>   recommend a wallet that sits on my computer, or phone, and what is the
>   best method for P2P exchange? How to go about it? –

i'm not fluent in english but i'll try my best!

1- Bitcoin not related to fiat currency, I thought you were talking about bitcoin core and transactions fee. which is not possible to lose bitcoins or even turning your bitcoins to any fiat currency.

2- coinbase isn't recommended because they don't provides full access to bitcoins. its just like PayPal. Your bitcoins in there are just bunch of numbers. And they are custodial Bitcoin wallet.

3- I recommend you to install Bitcoin-core from bitcoin.org but if you don't want to download the whole blockchain(145 GB) and your usage for bitcoin is just simple. You can use blockchain.info they are non-custodial bitcoin wallet and gives you full access to your bitcoins , nobody can track your account and no verification needed.

4- Localbitcoins.com.

Comment: To follow on with a few more question, could you please expand. 1) When you say "Bitcoin not related to fiat currency" what do you mean? 2) "I guess you're using coinbase.com which is not recommended" - I initially tried with those guys but their website was appaling so couldn't even verify my identity. So no. But out of interest, why are they not recommended? 3) Re. "find another wallet", would you recommend a wallet that sits on my computer, or phone, and what is the best method for P2P exchange? How to go about it?

Answer (score -2):

In the United States, the basic rate for all purchases and sales transactions is 4%. Coinbase will waive a portion of the cryptocurrency transaction fee based on the payment method you use.